# Data file only have 10 cols, got error "line 1 did not have 11 elements" when I'm loading txt in R

Tags: r

I come across an error when I'm trying to loading a txt file in R. 
The error message is like this:

> "Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : line 1 did not have 11 elements"

My txt file only has 10 cols, data is basically clean and neat. There are some rows are not aligning strictly, because they have long string in the first col, so other values are pushed right, aligning with other cols.  There's not missing values. 
How can I load this file properly?

```
employment = read.table('Employment.txt', header = T)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `fill` argument as `TRUE` to take of cases where there are more elements in one of the cells

```
read.table('Employment.txt', header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!! My problem is solved.